# DB2 on Cloud Account Reactivation not working

Tags: db2, ibm-cloud, feature-activation

I am an IBM employee who created a DB2 on Cloud service.  I received a message that I need to reactivate my account, with a link.  Clicking the link does not reactivate the account.

When I go to the DB2 on Cloud console there remains a "Reactivate Free Tier" button. Clicking this just brings me the same dashboard the link takes me to and it does not contain (or where I can not find) my DB2 on Cloud service (and it does not reactivate the account)

When trying to log into the DB2 on Cloud database, I continue to receive the error message:
Connection authorization failure occurred. Reason: User ID or Password invalid. ERRORCODE=-4214, SQLSTATE=28000

Comment: Contact IBM support, this is nothing for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Benjamin Schubert was able to reactivate my account.  I've copied Benjamin's response below:

---

There is a bug with syndicated instances that we're working to resolve. In the meantime I've reactivated your instance manually. By the time reactivation comes back around (30 days from now) the issue will be fixed.